# Typescript fail to detect parameter type in intersecting functions

Tags: typescript

I have a variable which can be a Set or a Map. The first parameter of the function in `forEach` it the same, but TypeScript falls back to `any`.

```js
    declare let setOrMap: Map<string,boolean>|Set<boolean>;
    setOrMap.forEach((myBool)=>{
      // myBool is any 8-/
    });
```

The signature is this:
`(method) forEach(callbackfn: ((value: boolean, key: string, map: Map<string, boolean>) => void) & ((value: boolean, value2: boolean, set: Set<boolean>) => void), thisArg: any): void`

Is this a known bug / missing feature (did not find a matching issue in ts github repo) or did i missed something?

Comment: Probably a limitation of contextual typing. I don't think contextual typing works for parameters at all if we are dealing with an overloaded signature (and that is what the intersection really works out to, an overloaded signature) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAZgdgFXNAvFAFOg9gLigIyywBsIBDOAGii2AAsIAnPOAVwFt8mBKKFAPigA3LAEsAJrwBkGbHkIlyVGvSZ4AzsEai4Ac14DhYyQChSwWHDzwkkPlDB9BAbwC+UAPQeHUUeqgUIFBAA

Comment: You can add the type manually to `myBool` and if you use `noImplicitAny` ts will raise an error if it `any` is implicitly inferred